# Exporting large quantities of data and memory issues

Tags: php, mysql, performance, excel, memory

I'm not having a specific problem. I would like to hear ideas and techniques concerning memory issues.

Let's say I have:

- 100 000 products on products table
- 100 000 product names on product names table
- 100 000 product descriptions on product descriptions table
- 200 000 product pictures on product pictures table

I want to export these to a excel file. How can I do it within a normal server.

Should I query all products and joined tables or use limit and offset and do it like 50 000 a time?

Should I loop the mysql results and save the data to a file every once in a while and then combine them at the end?

Should I create multiple smaller excel files and combine them at the end?

So the real question is what techniques are you using to prevent having memory issues with too large mysql result, too large variable size (saving whole mysql data to an array), too large excel variable data (creating one huge excel vs. creating multiple small and combining them).

PS. The ideas doesn't have to relate to the excel example I gave you. I want to learn how to handle lots of data in general.

Comment: It depends, first of all, on whether you want to create a real Excel BIFF (.xls) or OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) file, or whether a simple comma-separated value (csv) file is adequate for your needs: if the latter, then you write each row as you read the result from the database rather than building any large arrays in memory

Answer (score 0):

Insert these lines on top of your phpmyadmin config.inc.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M'); // set memory to match your available RAM.
set_time_limit(0); // unlimit script time to run
```

Open your browser, run export to excel. Leave the browser until it's done.

If you want a custom report, then just query all data out (If your RAM has lots of room left, it's no problem.) and do the report all you want. Insert above lines on top of your code before run too.

Comment: I'm looking a way to go around the memory issues using different techniques. I think the worst way is to keep doing things wrong and just to increase the memory limit.